# What's the best way to access files outside the Azure function's project directory?

Tags: azure, configuration, azure-functions

I'm new to the azure functions. We've some configuration files(JSON) that need to be accessed from the Azure function as well as from some other workflows. So, we want to keep those files outside the Azure function project directory in the same repo.

All config files are placed under one folder & there'll be more files added to that folder in the future. What's the best way to access those files or add their reference in the Azure function? Is it possible to add them in a such way that if any new file is added, it'll also be available to the function?

Also, how do I make those files available to function after the deployment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand that your scenario is you have some configuration files (JSON Fomat) that should be used in both the Azure Functions Projects and also other workflows.

Theer is a feature in Azure called Azure [App Configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-app-configuration/concept-config-file) Store is the better place for storing the configuration files especially JSON Kind of files.

It is the central repository where you can use that App Configuration Store to number of the projects both in Cloud and Local Environment.

You can also import and export the configuration data and use it in the code.
For any short time reading the configuration values in-between the code flows, you can utilize the REST APIs available for configuration stores.

##### Updated Answer:

Another place to store the multiple Configuration Files (JSON) is the Azure Blob Storage.
Whatever the Config file you want in the application code for specific point of time, you can use it. Check SO #[72960470](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72960470/reading-multiple-json-files-from-azure-storage-into-python-dataframe) where the user @*Venkatesan* provided the solution for storing and reading the multiple JSON Files from the Azure Blob Storage to the Application (Python Stack).

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Can we store multiple files in a single Azure App Configuration resource & segregate those files? Or will the configurations in files be stored as key-value pairs? Also, is there any other option than using Azure app configuration?

Comment: In Azure Blob Storage also, you can store the Config (JSON) File in multiple and you can retrieve or use them during your requirement.